# Add custom AuthenticationProvider to Spring Security in JHipster

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, jhipster

My main goal is to authenticate certain APIs differently in a JHipster application.

Right now I'm using JHipster built-in stateless JWT authentication mechanism, which works just fine. I would like to create a subset of APIs where an API key is needed to authenticate a tenant (not a user) instead of JWT.

I was trying to add multiple HttpSecurity instances with [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) approach (order(1) is my custom configuration, order(2) is jwt). My own custom AuthorizationProvider's *authenticate* method fires, and returns a token, but I still got a JWT error message.

Despite the fact that my authentication was successful JWTFilter invoked while it shouldn't be.

What am I missing?

My log:

```
[nio-8080-exec-3] c.s.b.s.i.IntegrationAuthFilter          : Request is to process authentication
[nio-8080-exec-3] c.s.b.s.i.IntegrationAuthFilter          : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: com.example.app.security.integration.IntegrationAuthToken@ffffffc4: Principal: asd; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
[nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:223)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:458)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:518)
    at com.example.app.security.jwt.TokenProvider.validateToken(TokenProvider.java:98)
    at com.example.app.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:40)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am in exactly the same situation.